# Are breadboads available in EasyEDA?

Tags: simulator

So far I have been using TinkerCAD which has them but I am unable to find them on EasyEDA Library. Are connectors supposed to do the same thing? I get this empty rectangle in the EasyEDA library which I am unable to make sense of.

Comment: look at your arduino board ... do you see connectors for every single pin of every component?

Comment: you are supposed to draw a schematic diagram ... here is an example ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/523839/atmega328p-development-board

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for responding! I am still confused. When it comes to the Arduino, where do I type the code in order to simulate (TinkerCAD has a side window to do this)? As for the breadboard issue, do header pins work in the same way (ie do all the header pins on a single header have the same potential, much like a row on a breadboard)?

Comment: again, look at the header pins on your arduino board ... do they look connected all together?

Comment: I think that EasyEDA can simulate electronic circuits ... it does not simulate programming in devices

Comment: I think I get it. So in EasyEDA the "rows" of a breadboard would be redundant as you can just sketch regular parallel wires wherever needed or label the "nodes" which are meant to be at the same potential with the same term (?). But what about the power rails? Would tagging all the nodes which use the same power source as ##V_cc## do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EasyEDA is not designed for diy prototypes like TinkerCAD is.  EasyEDA's purpose is to simulate electronic circuits and design circuit boards for those circuit designs.  Because of this they don't have a breadboard object because there would be no point in having one, since you can just connect virtual wires in the schematic mode and wire traces in the board design mode.

Furthermore, it doesn't support simulating a full Arduino board with code.

Comment: So if a number of wires were to be connected to a node, for a breadboard I would connect them all to each hole in a row as all points in a row have the same potential and are connected to each other. For EasyEDA, would labelling all the points with the same label also work? So if a bunch of components were to be connected in parallel to a voltage source (V1), would labelling the relevant points with a node called V1 be the same as drawing parallel connections with wires? Thank you for helping!

Comment: If you are drawing an electrical schematic then the practice of labeling to signify a common connection point is common.  For example you'll see multiple GND labels on schematic diagrams.  On a circuit board layout, however, you wouldn't want to do this because the whole point of a circuit board layout is draw all the physical traces and connection points that will be make the circuit design function when made into a physical circuit board.